# Loading pushpin in the forge viewer does not respect the viewerState

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are using the "Autodesk.BIM360.Extension.PushPin" extension inside the forge viewer to enable push pins.

When a push pin has been added to the model, we serialize the pushpin data and store it in our database. An example of such a pushpin is here:

```
{
    "id": "12",
    "label": "12",
    "status": "quality_issues-not_approved",
    "position": {
        "x": 15.324803588519861,
        "y": -10.150864635427533,
        "z": -5.532972775562976
    },
    "type": "issues",
    "objectId": 24518,
    "externalId": "d9a1e318-14d0-4d08-b7ab-6d1c331454c2-002793d1",
    "viewerState": {
        "seedURN": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6MDQyY2QwMmUtNzU0Yi00ZDY2LTgyYTMtNjBmYjFlOWVjMjcxL2U5ODAxZTA4LTUwZjQtNDc0ZS05ZWU4LTAxYWQ0ZGM0ODFiYl9WMV9Lb25nZXN0aWVuKzMwKy0rVGlsYnlnbmluZystK0clMjVDMyUyNUE2bGRlbmRlK2QuKzA1LjA2LnJ2dA",
        "objectSet": [{
            "id": [],
            "isolated": [],
            "hidden": [],
            "explodeScale": 0,
            "idType": "lmv"
        }],
        "viewport": {
            "name": "",
            "eye": ["-15.17842530349136", "-0.9048862425583284", "0.6506974303790392"],
            "target": ["-22.06049144652811", "0.915848677106827", "-0.4205110420886964"],
            "up": [-0.14385076361076257, 0.038057482024001874, 0.9888673247056924],
            "worldUpVector": [0, 0, 1],
            "pivotPoint": ["-22.510046835506888", "1.6223793651751013", "3.668585646439837"],
            "distanceToOrbit": 7.198985875545766,
            "aspectRatio": 1.491792224702381,
            "projection": "orthographic",
            "isOrthographic": true,
            "orthographicHeight": 7.198985875545767
        },
        "renderOptions": {
            "environment": "Boardwalk",
            "ambientOcclusion": {
                "enabled": true,
                "radius": 13.123359580052492,
                "intensity": 1
            },
            "toneMap": {
                "method": 1,
                "exposure": -7,
                "lightMultiplier": -1e-20
            },
            "appearance": {
                "ghostHidden": true,
                "ambientShadow": true,
                "antiAliasing": true,
                "progressiveDisplay": true,
                "swapBlackAndWhite": false,
                "displayLines": true,
                "displayPoints": true
            }
        },
        "cutplanes": [],
        "globalOffset": {
            "x": -20.808594999999997,
            "y": 6.686511499999999,
            "z": 8.456207
        }
    },
    "objectData": {
        "guid": "6de5f80c-73da-30ae-b2d1-8a78f177c2a4",
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6MDQyY2QwMmUtNzU0Yi00ZDY2LTgyYTMtNjBmYjFlOWVjMjcxL2U5ODAxZTA4LTUwZjQtNDc0ZS05ZWU4LTAxYWQ0ZGM0ODFiYl9WMV9Lb25nZXN0aWVuKzMwKy0rVGlsYnlnbmluZystK0clMjVDMyUyNUE2bGRlbmRlK2QuKzA1LjA2LnJ2dA",
        "viewableId": "aaff5911-e8b1-4ae2-b41c-4284d0703eb4-00150218",
        "viewName": "{3D}"
    }
}
```

We then load the pushpin into the model again at a later point (when the user reopens the model), like this:

```
pushPinExtension.loadItems([pushPinItem]);
```

The result is that the pushpin is added in the model at the correct place, but the viewer state is incorrect. It seems like the viewer state for the pushpin is set to the viewer state of the model at the time when we load the pushpin - and not to the viewer state stored inside the pushpin.

Is this expected behaviour? - and if so, how do I use the viewer state from the pushpin instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not explicitly load the viewer state stored in the pushpin separately after loading the pushpin:

```
pushPinExtension.loadItems([pushPinItem]);
viewer.restoreState(pushPinItem.viewerState)
```

**EDIT:**

Try restore the viewer state when an item is clicked - subscribe to the click event with:

```
   viewer.restoreState(...)
   //...
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Bryan! It is not at the time we load the pushpin that the viewstate should be restored, it is when the user clicks the pushpin afterwards. What happens now is that the camera moves to the “initial” view when any issue is clicked, like described in my question

Comment: Sure I will Engineering know that this is an issue and hopefully they can get that fixed soon - in the meantime you can restore the viewer state when an item is clicked - see edit